# Could you show me how to convert checkboxes to dropdown fields in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, dropdown

Is it possible to convert checkboxes to dropdown options? Here's my code. Is it also possible to include checkboxes within the dropdown for multi-selection?

```
<ul class="kw-features-list">

    <?php foreach( $job_tags as $feature ): ?>
        <li>
        <label for="kw-feature-<?php echo esc_attr( $feature->slug ) ?>" class="checkbox-inline">
            <?php $checked = ( in_array( $feature->slug, $atts['selected_feature'] ) ) ? ' checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
            <input class="search_feature" name="search_feature[]" <?php echo esc_attr($checked)  ?>        
             id="kw-feature-<?php echo esc_attr( $feature->slug ) ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo esc_attr($feature->slug) ?>">
            <?php echo esc_attr($feature->name) ?>
        </label>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul><!--/ .kw-features-list-->
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your existing code, try the following by setting the necessary classes.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="search_feature">
    <?php foreach( $job_tags as $feature ): ?>
        <option <?= ( in_array( $feature->slug, $atts['selected_feature'] ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>
                <?php echo esc_attr($feature->name) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```